# Use Powershell to change font within a shape (MS Word)

Tags: powershell, ms-word, textbox

I'm extremely new to Powershell (as in, this is the first solution I've tried). I'm trying to create a solution that will change all fonts within a given Word document to Arial. So far I've composed this solution which works for body text.

```
$WordExts = '.docx','.doc','.docm'
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $false
$folder = Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot | ? {$_.Extension -in $WordExts}
foreach ($file in $folder){
    echo $file.FullName
    $worddoc = $Word.Documents.Open($file.FullName)
    $Selection = $Word.Selection
    $worddoc.Select()
    $Selection.Font.Name = "Arial"
    $worddoc.Close()
    $worddoc = $null
}
$Word.Quit()
$Word = $null
```

This changes the body text of the Word document as intended. However, it is not capturing or making changes to strings within text boxes or the table of contents. Which method do I need to use to target these shapes and make changes to the text within them? I've been trying to look through the Powershell documentation but have been unable to find the answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have sample code for you, but it's the *Word Object Model*  documentation (and samples, often written in VBA), specifically how to iterate "storyranges", that you need to look for. A quick search took me to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174455/powershell-script-to-find-and-replace-in-word-document-including-header-footer but no idea if that is usable code.

Comment: @jonsson Thanks for the link! This helped me set the font for the headers and footers. Finding the text boxes took some more doing.

Answer (score 0):

I started with the link in jonsson's comment, and was able to figure out how to iterate through headers and footers.

Text boxes took some more work, since they aren't located in the same place. I asked for some help from my husband and we started using echo to look at what was in all those sections (and then in THOSE sections) until we found the right object. Also, while headers and footers are clearly defined, text boxes are scattered across several different sections, so we had to iterate through each section in the document to look for the textbox object ShapeRange. I also later added a method to remove document protection, because it was holding up the script.

```
$WordExts = '.docx','.doc','.docm'
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $false
$folder = Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot | ? {$_.Extension -in $WordExts}

#Remove document protection

ForEach ($file in $folder) {
    $file | Unblock-File
}

#Iterate through each file in the parent folder

foreach ($file in $folder){
    echo $file.FullName
    $worddoc = $Word.Documents.Open($file.FullName)

#Change the font in the main body of the document

    $Selection = $Word.Selection
    $worddoc.Select()
    $Selection.Font.Name = "Arial"

#Iterate through each section to locate ShapeRange (textbox) to change font

    $target = $worddoc.Sections.Count
    $count = 1;
    While($count -lt ($target + 1)){
        ForEach ($section in $worddoc.Sections($count).Range.ShapeRange) {
            ForEach($item in $section.TextFrame){                
                ForEach($i in $item.TextRange){
                    $i.Font.Name = "Arial"
                }
            }            
        }
        $count++
    }

#Iterate through each header and footer to change font

    ForEach ($section in $worddoc.Sections) {
        ForEach ($header in $section.Headers) {
            $header.Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
        }
        ForEach ($footer in $section.Footers) {
            $footer.Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
        }
    }        
    $worddoc.Close()
    $worddoc = $null
}
$Word.Quit()
$Word = $null
```